# How to integrate "Recent Posts by Others" posts from Facebook's Timeline page to my site?

Tags: facebook, plugins

I'm trying to get "Recent Posts by Others" posts(/feeds) from Facebook's Timeline page and integrate to my site.
Previously i tried facebook comments plugin, then i realized it wasn't comments :(. But i like facebook comments plugins, it's easy. 
 
For example, http://www.facebook.com/SPG has "Recent Posts by Others" posts, and i want these posts add to my site, then users'll have opportunity to add their posts and comments.
 i can see posts as JSON from there: https://graph.facebook.com/spg/posts (or /spg/feed) 
 I really don't want to work on JSON data, maybe facebook has some plugin or service to show these posts. Do you have any recommendations? (It would be best, if there solution like facebook comments plugins for posts)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I think there is no such thing... The complete list of Facebook social plugins is documented [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/)
You might have to work with JSON...

Comment: it seems you're right, but it's not easy implementing identical facebook post, it's [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) of facebook. i hope somebody has better solution, otherwise i'll accept your answer :)